# Reading/Writing XML nodes containing special characters

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have a requirement to convert string to XmlNode and add it to existing Xaml file.

My Xml string contains special characters.

Here is my Xml string(which comes from the T4 template) which contains "&#xE10F" as attribute value.

```
<Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            Background="{StaticResource TopAppbarTileBackground}" 
            x:Name="chanceAppBarButton">
        <Grid Margin="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock ***Text="&#xE10F;"*** VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TopAppbarIconStyle}"/>

            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource TopAppbarTileTextStyle}" x:Uid="chanceAppBarButtonLabel"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid></Button>
```

Here is the code(partial) which converts Xml String to Node and append it to existing file.

```
 var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(filePath);
        XmlElement rootElement = xmldoc.DocumentElement;
     XmlNode xmlNode = CreateNodeFromXmlString(xmlNodeString, namespaceList);  
XmlNode importNode = rootElement.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(xmlNode, true);
     rootElement.AppendChild(importNode);  // Add Xml node to Parent Element
     xmldoc.Save(filePath);  // Save Xml file

     private static XmlNode CreateNodeFromXmlString(string xml, Dictionary<string, string> namespaceList)
    {
        var newDataTemplateDocument = new XmlDocument();
        var nameTable = new NameTable();

        var xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);

        foreach (var namespaceItem in namespaceList)
        {
            xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace(namespaceItem.Key, namespaceItem.Value);
        }

        var context = new XmlParserContext(nameTable, xmlNamespaceManager, null, XmlSpace.None);

        var reader = new XmlTextReader(xml.Trim(), XmlNodeType.Element, context);

        return newDataTemplateDocument.ReadNode(reader);
    }
```

The output of the above code is(just showing button control):

```
<Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            Background="{StaticResource TopAppbarTileBackground}" 
            x:Name="chanceAppBarButton">
        <Grid Margin="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text=" î„" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TopAppbarIconStyle}"/>

            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource TopAppbarTileTextStyle}" x:Uid="chanceAppBarButtonLabel"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid></Button>
```

Here “&#xE10F” got replaced with “î„”.

Any idea how can I stop escaping the special characters while reading/writing XML?

Comment: Firstly I don't see your xml encoding. You need to use the same encoding when creating Output format.

Comment: Could you please giveany link or example on how to specify encoding while using xmldocument.Save?

Comment: Do you really have to go through all that stuff? Why not just parse your XML string into a document, then copy the root node?

Comment: Thanks John for your reply. but I am reading my button xml string from one of my T4 template and then I have to append that string to my existing file.

Comment: why not use base64 encoding for the text?

Answer (score 6):

By default, XML is written out in the UTF8 encoding. In UTF8, characters above the ASCII range are represented as two- to three-byte sequences. I haven't checked, but I would assume that the XML serializer did exactly the right thing and that if you parse the XML you'll get back your 0xE10F character. From XML's point of view, this is a difference that makes no difference.

If you really want the numeric character entity used instead, tell your serializer to use ASCII as its encoding. ASCII can't represent the 0xE10F character directly, and the serializer will realize this and use the character entity to work around the problem.

Comment: Could you please give any link or sample? As I tried using Encoding like below:
var context = new XmlParserContext(nameTable, xmlNamespaceManager, null, XmlSpace.None, Encoding.ASCII);
but it didn't work.

Comment: I assume you're working in C++ and using Microsoft's System.Xml classes. If so, a quick look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says you need to set the [`XmlDeclaration.Encoding` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldeclaration.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before calling `save()`. This requires that your document have an `XmlDeclaration`.

Or you can simply accept that the output encoding defaults to UTF8, _not_ ASCII, and that the file is entirely correct as it stands even if it isn't what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use base64 encoding or use the CDATA tag for storing complex data in XML.

For CDATA example refer to http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp